# Compiler error when including C++ code in the iPhone project

Tags: c++, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to include some C++ code into my iPhone project and I'm getting the following compiler error:

**"error:expected initializer before '<' token"**

at this code construct:

```
  template<typename T, P_UINT_32 BEG, bool OQ, bool OVR, bool DBG>
  P_UINT_32 EKType<T, BEG, OQ, OVR, DBG>::getSizeX() const {
    return n;
  }
```

It looks like the XCode compiler is not recognizing this as a valid C++ syntax. I have named my C++ files with .h and .mm, and I've set the types of the files to sourcecode.cpp.h and sourcecode.cpp.cpp

Anyone has an idea as to why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the header being included by a .M file *somewhere*. It's amazing how these things can get pulled in, so make sure **all** of your .M files are renamed .MM.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I renamed all .m files to .mm, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You're going to have to look at your build log (Shift+Cmd+B). Look at which file is being compiled when the error is found (NOT which file is opened when you double-click the error). Then look at the inclusion chain to figureout whether any non MM files are being compiled.

Comment: Thanks. So, I'm looking at the build log and the file that's being compiled at the time or error is a .cpp file. That file includes a .h (c++) and that's it. Unless you mean something else by inclusion chain?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to name a file .mm if the file contains both Objective-C and C++.

If the file only contains C++, it should have the extension .cpp

If the file is a mix of ObjC and C++, then it should have the extension .mm and have its type set as sourcecode.cpp.objcpp

Comment: yes, thanks. I changed them to .cpp but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the source file you are trying to compile includes the declaration of the `EKType` class (or struct) and the declaration `P_UINT_32`?

I would think you'd get a similar error if the compiler wasn't aware of `EKType` or `P_UINT_32`.